# Transitioning ownership of a file between two deb packages

Tags: debian, deb

Package `a.deb` currently provides a file `/etc/file.conf`, we'd like to update this package so it no longer provides this file and instead it would be provided by package `b.deb`.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /root/b.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/file', which is also in package a
```

Now `dpkg` doesn't like that — we'd have to remove the package `a` first, but we don't really have control over the upgrade process. We can't just add a `--force-overwrite` option or anything like that, we only have control over repository and packages themselves.

Can we do some shenanigans with pre-install scripts maybe? Maybe there's a proper way to make this kind of ownership transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move a file from one package (`a`) to another (`b`), you need to update `a` so that it no longer installs the file, then update `b` so that it installs the file, and declares in its `control` file that it

```
Breaks: a (<< ...)
Replaces: a (<< ...)
```

where `...` is the updated version of `a`.

Then `dpkg` will accept that `b` is allowed to replace (parts of) `a`, and it won’t allow `a` and `b` to be installed in conflicting versions (*i.e.* versions which both try to install the moved file). `Replaces` can be confusing — it applies even if the replacement is only partial. During upgrades, `apt` will know what to do: it will upgrade `a` first, and then upgrade `b`.

See [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#overwriting-files-and-replacing-packages-replaces) for details.